# Appstore sandbox test user Invalid Products

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am working on inapp purchases using sandbox test user accounts. I am getting list of products when I make SKProductRequest. In one device I am getting products fine. But in other device, somehow my products are falling into invalid products. I am using same test account in both devices. Have anyone seen this kind issue anytime? What could possibly go wrong? The device that I am getting invalid products is an old ipad, iPad1. But in iPad2, everything works good.

Comment: Is the old iPad1 is on ios5 and the iPad2 is on ios6? Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652301/inapp-purchase-on-ios-5-vs-ios-6. Seems like they behave differently. Deleting and re-installing the app or just waiting a couple hours seem to fix it for some people.

Comment: no both of them are on iOS 5.1.1 unfortunately. But interesting fact in above mentioned post is jailbroken. I don't know that and I need to check that.

Comment: test users in inAppPurchases and game center don't work in devices with jailbreak. If you want to know if a device have jailbreak, look for cydia app, if it's installed the device have jailbreak